# Why is supossed that $\Bbb N$ is closed under this definition?

Tags: general-topology

It is a problem from the book of topology of Viro et al.:

> Consider the following property of a subset $F$ of the set $\mathbb{N}$ of positive integers: there is $n\in\mathbb{N}$  such that $F$ contains no arithmetic progressions of length $n$. Prove that subsets with this property together with the whole $\mathbb{N}$ form a collection of closed subsets in some topology on $\mathbb{N}$.

I can understand why the finite union of sets and intersection of sets are closed. I see too that the empty set is closed because you only need an intersection of disjoint sets to take it.

But I cant see, in a clear way, why $\Bbb N$ is closed... I cant take a $n\in\Bbb N$ that holds for the whole $\Bbb N$. What Im overlooking? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It says "subsets with this property *together* with the whole $\mathbb{N}$", not that the natural numbers actually do have this property.

Comment: But why is $\Bbb N$ closed then @Lukas Geyer?

Comment: This is not what the question is actually asking. It declares sets to be closed if they have a certain property or are all natural numbers, and your job is to check whether this system of sets satisfies the properties of a topology.

Comment: You have to prove the subsets are a base for a topology.  I believe all you have to do is show the set of subsets is closed under finite intersections and arbitrary unions, or something like that.

Comment: The problem statement seems ambiguous. "s collection of closed subsets in some topology" seems to suggst that one has to show: There exists a topology such that the given sets are among the closed sets. Bu tthis is clear by picking the discrete topology ... To make sense of the probelm statemet it should read: "... subsets with this property, together with $\Bbb N$, form *the* collectionof closed subsets in some topolgy of $\Bbb N$.